# Wait for a thread to finish before continuing the current thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have this in a method:

```
Runnable task = new PostLoadRunnable(tool, archive);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task);
```

But I want to make it so that the current method does not continue until the task thread has completed. I want to do something like `join()` but I can't work out how to do it. `task.join()` and `Thread.task.join()` doesn't work and `Thread.currentThread().join()` doesn't give me any options to join it to the thread that I want.

How do I stop the method until task is finished?

Comment: Why you are using a Thread if you want to continue when is finished? The idea of Threading is execute code in paralel. Sorry for the mediocre english.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread.join` won't work because that refers to the thread where you're calling InvokeLater, not the actual background/event thread.  Does `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` do what you want?

Comment: You don't want to wait for a thread to finish here - you want to wait for some code to finish.

Comment: because I have other threads that must be completed first then I need task to run and complete and then continue on.

Comment: @wrschneider99 It says I cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread. I'm not very good at threads and don't really understand too well. Join sounds like what I want, but I don't know how to "attach" it to the task and current threads

Comment: Look into `wait()` and `notify()`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a `CountDownLatch`. In your `PostLoadRunnable` run method you can have the following code in the finally section.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

CountDownLatch latch = CountDownLatch(1);
Runnable task = new PostLoadRunnable(tool, archive, latch);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task);
latch.await();
```

Comment: This sounds perfect, but freezes the application forever, I would've thought that it would only freeze for a couple of seconds.

Comment: @Aequitas If it's only required for a couple of seconds why freeze at all?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this at all. You state in comments that this code runs in the event dispatcher thread. You *must not* block this thread. Otherwise you will freeze the entire UI and the user will be most unhappy.

What you *probably* should do is disable the relevant parts of the UI until the task has completed. But without knowing your actual wider requirement it isn't possible to be sure.

Comment: A freeze is okay as it is loading a file so nothing should be able to be done, most applications will freeze when you are loading a file.

Comment: It's not just a freeze. It's a complete lockup of your application. When you call `invokeLater`, you are telling Swing to invoke that task on the event dispatcher thread. But if you then block the event dispatcher thread to wait for the task to finish, you make it impossible for the task to ever execute, as you are blocking the thread that it needs to run on. As you have discovered with @shazin's answer.

Comment: @Aequitas Users will regard any application that freezes as broken. I certainly do. They will think it has crashed, try to close it, etc. It is *disabling the UI* that is OK, just. Why do you think you need to do *anything* about this?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I don't understand shouldn't it be executing on a different thread? Isn't that the whole point? So the event dispatcher thread should wait for the thread that's started by invokeLater to finish

Comment: @Aequitas It's the other way around. If you start a different thread, but you need to do something with the user interface, you can use `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait` to schedule some work on the Swing dispatcher thread. Although `invokeLater` *can* also be invoked from the dispatcher thread, there's not much point because you are already allowed to touch the UI from the dispatcher thread.